# Reading ETW providers using go

Tags: winapi, go, etw

I'm trying to access the EnumerateTraceGuids function from Advapi32.dll in go.
I'm at the very early stage and still trying to decipher what is it that I must do. I have the following code that keeps giving me Error: 87, meaning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

I've used this file as a starting point though it's only writing and not reading : 
https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/logger/etwlogs/etwlogs_windows.go

Official documentation for the function I'm trying to call is here : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363713(v=vs.85).aspx

It requires GuidPropertiesArray [in, out] An array of pointers to TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES structures. This structure is the following (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364143(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
typedef struct _TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES {
  GUID    Guid;
  ULONG   GuidType;
  ULONG   LoggerId;
  ULONG   EnableLevel;
  ULONG   EnableFlags;
  BOOLEAN IsEnable;
} TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES, *PTRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES;
```

I have the following code to try and do this :

```
package main
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

const (
    win32CallSuccess = 0
    MaxProv = 50
    nbProviders = 50
)

var (
    modAdvapi32          = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("Advapi32.dll")
    procEnumerateTraceGuids = modAdvapi32.NewProc("EnumerateTraceGuids")
)

type ulong int32

type TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES struct {
    Guid syscall.GUID
    GuidType ulong
    LoggerId ulong
    EnableLevel ulong
    EnableFlags ulong
    IsEnable bool
}

func callEnumerateTraceGuids() error {
    GuidPropertiesArray:= make([]TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES, 1)
    ptr := &GuidPropertiesArray[0]
    ret, _, _ := procEnumerateTraceGuids.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&ptr)), MaxProv, nbProviders)
    if ret != win32CallSuccess {
        errorMessage := fmt.Sprintf("Failed to register ETW provider. Error: %d", ret)
        logrus.Error(errorMessage)
        return errors.New(errorMessage)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    callEnumerateTraceGuids()
}
```

At this point I'm not sure what is it that I must do. I've tried a lot of variation of initializing the array without success.
Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks !

Edit : Changed code based on comments but still getting the same error.

PS : This is my first time posting to stackoverflow and I've already been told that I'm lazy less than 12 hours after posting my question (yay!) so not sure I'm asking this right...I am not too familiar with go and never called windows DLL from go before and since I keep hitting that ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER I thought of reaching out to try and pass this first wall to be able to grasp some concepts at the same time. Hope this helps understands my request (ie. I come in peace).

Comment: Note that that API function accepts *a pointer to a pointer;* that is, it accept the address of a memory location containing an address of the array. You're passing the address of the array instead.

Comment: I tried this : GuidPropertiesArray:= make([]*TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES, 50)
    ptr := &GuidPropertiesArray[0]
    ret, _, _ := procEnumerateTraceGuids.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&ptr)), MaxProv, nbProviders)

Comment: So you tried that, *and?…* Still, my guess is that you 1) should allocate an array of structs (not pointers);2) take the address of its 1st element and place it to a variable; 3) take its address and pass to that function.

Comment: All-in-all, that's not how such problems are solved. You search for example usage of win32 API functions in C or C++ and then translate them to Go (of course if you're lazy to just carefully read the API doc page).

Comment: BTW the example is right there in the function doc. The key to translating that C to Go is that C's `malloc` and `realloc` return an (untyped) pointer even though you typically allocate memory for an array of values whose type is not pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I had a bit of free time and an access to a Windows XP box,
so I've decided to dust off my Windows programming skills
and wrote a working solution:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    modAdvapi32             = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("advapi32")
    procEnumerateTraceGuids = modAdvapi32.NewProc("EnumerateTraceGuids")
)

type traceGuidProperties struct {
    guid        syscall.GUID
    guidType    uint32
    loggerId    uint32
    enableLevel uint32
    enableFlags uint32
    isEnable    uint32
}

func enumerateTraceGuids(ptr **traceGuidProperties, count uint32, out *uint32) error {
    rc, _, _ := procEnumerateTraceGuids.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ptr)),
        uintptr(count), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(out)))
    if rc != 0 {
        return syscall.Errno(rc)
    }
    return nil
}

func enumTraceGuids() ([]*traceGuidProperties, error) {
    var errMoreData = syscall.Errno(234)

    var (
        dummyProps traceGuidProperties
        dummyPtr   = &dummyProps

        count uint32
    )

    err := enumerateTraceGuids(&dummyPtr, 0, &count)
    if err != errMoreData {
        return nil, err
    }

    items := make([]*traceGuidProperties, count)
    for i := range items {
        items[i] = new(traceGuidProperties)
    }

    for {
        err = enumerateTraceGuids(&items[0], count, &count)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
        if err != errMoreData {
            return nil, err
        }
        for i := 0; i < int(count)-len(items); i++ {
            items = append(items, new(traceGuidProperties))
        }
    }

    return items[:count], nil
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    data, err := enumTraceGuids()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("len(data)=%d\n", len(data))
    for i := range data {
        log.Println(*(data[i]))
    }
}
```

The key points:

- I was wrong when I told you that
  «you … should allocate an array of structs (not pointers)»—in fact
  `EnumerateTraceGuids` indeed expects an array of pointers.
- As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273324/720999),
  there are two subtleties with how `EnumerateTraceGuids` works:

  - Contrary to what its documentation states,
    it actually supports being called with its `PropertyArrayCount`
    parameter set to 0, in which case it's expected to return `ERROR_MORE_DATA`
    while having set `GuidCount` to the number of elements of the input
    array required for the (next) call to complete successfully.
    IOW, that way we know how many trace GUIDs the system currently
    "knows about".
  - Still, even in this case, the function performs validity check
    on the input array (see below).
- As it turns out, the function expects an array of pointers to
  `TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES` blocks *allocated by you.*

  In other words, if it says you it knows about 10 trace GUIDs,
  you have to allocate 10 values of type `TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES`,
  then make an array of 10 pointers to those values and pass a pointer
  to the 1st element of that array to the function.
- Notice that there's an inherent race between changes occuring
  in the system (those traces added or removed for any number of reasons)
  and the calls to `EnumerateTraceGuids`.

  This means if the first call to this function told you it "knows"
  about 10 trace GUIDs, on the next call it may turn out
  there's already 20 trace GUIDs, or 5 GUIDs
  (or any other number of them FWIW).

  So we account for both of these possibilities in the following way:

  1. First we do a call with a pointer to a single (but valid)
     `TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES` value, allocated statically 
     (hence the function "sees" what looks like an array of a single element),
     while telling the function the input "array" has zero elements.

     We expect the function to fail with `ERROR_MORE_DATA`
     and put the actual number of trace GUIDs it "knows" about into the variable
     we've supplied it a pointer to.
  2. We allocate that much `TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES` memory blocks
     the function indicated on the first call.
     For this, we use the `new()` built-in function which behaves somewhat
     like `malloc()` in the standard C library—it allocates the memory for
     a value of the specified type and returns a pointer to the allocated
     memory block.
  3. We create an array of pointers to these allocated memory blocks
     and call `EnumerateTraceGuids` again.
  4. If it succeeds, we handle the possibility it returned less
     elements than we've allocated, and reslice our slice.
  5. If it fails with `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, we extend our slice with
     whatever the number of elements is needed (allocating memory for their
     `TRACE_GUID_PROPERTIES` blocks first), and try calling the function again.
- The "magic number" 234 is the actual code for the `ERROR_MORE_DATA` value.

Sorry for the initial confusion.

Comment: Thank you a LOT for this. I haven't had the time yet to compare but tested very quickly your solution and of course it worked :). Huge thanks for the time spent.

Comment: BTW, inspecting [this](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/) hints at a couple of things: 1) there's no need to use `golang.org/x/sys/windows`—the stock `syscall` should have the same stuff by now; 2) that package seem to export the `ERROR_MODE_DATA` value alreasy, so no need to to that explicitly as I did. I'd try these suggestions and see if they work out.